# Python Selenium: Unable to find a element when the element already exists

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

I'm having issues looking for this specific input:

`<input type="text" class="criteriaFieldInput ui-autocomplete-input" id="KEYWORD" isautosuggest="true" suggestid="1" isolf="false" isphrase="false" value="0090653 " autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">`

I tried the following solution [from this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369249/python-with-selenium-unable-to-locate-element-which-really-exist)

 but still wasn't able to get it to resolve

I'm always getting this output:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="KEYWORD"]`

Does anyone have any other solution I can try to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This XPATH is wrong. You have to change to `//*[@id='KEYWORD']`

But you can find with ID  `driver.find_element_by_id("KEYWORD")`